# Remove 10 Rows in Dataframe of each Label

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 6 different labels and would like to remove 10 rows of each label and add this to another dataframe as a test data set and remove them from the original df. Would appreciate any help!

I am able to sample 10 rows of each label type

```
        df_tester = pd.concat(g.sample(10) for idx, g in df.groupby('Label'))
```

but would like to remove these rows from the original dataframe to put them into another one.

i.e., if the length of df is 650, then I create a sample df_tester of 60, then the original df should now be 590

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indices are unique, you can use:

```
df_tester = df.groupby('Label').sample(n=10)

df = df.drop(df_tester.index)
```